Configuring a SecurityFilterChain makes the unmatched parts of the application open by default
Spring Security is closed by default, so if I configure no SecurityFilterChain, the whole spring boot application responds 401, which is expected.
Now if I configure a SecurityFilterChain for a part of the application (/api), I noticed that the unconfigured part (/whatever) become open by default:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher("/api/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
            .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest().denyAll())
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}

Configuring securityMatcher("/api/**") should not affect URLs not matched by this pattern, and the unconfigured parts should remain closed by default.
I find that behaviour very surprising and would like to know if this is intended or not.

You would need to add another security matcher for the rest, else the filters won't execute. Your SecurityFilterChain overrides the default one registered by Spring Boot.

The annswer of M. Deinum is correct: the behaviour is expected. See the documentation.

NOTE: Specifying a securityMatcher overrides this default.


WARNING: If no filter chain matches a particular request, the request is not protected by Spring Security.

